# Factorial function for a math library in C++

Tags: c++, beginner

I am trying to code up a basic combinatorial math library for C++. Started with the implementation of the factorial function. Here I include the code and the test code. Please review.

1. Is the way of throwing argument exceptions the best way to do it?
2. Am I using the Test code the correct way for testing exceptions?
3. Any other advice will be welcome.

N.B: I have seen that the boost library uses a tabularized approach with gamma functions. I shall do these optimizations later.

```
namespace Combinatorics
{
    unsigned long long factorial(int n) 
    {
        if (n < 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument("The argument cannot be negative");
        unsigned long long fact = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if ((ULLONG_MAX / i) >= fact)
            {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument("The argument is too large");
            }
        }
        return fact;
    }
}

TEST(CombinatorialTestCase, Factorial) 
{
    EXPECT_EQ(120, Combinatorics::factorial(5));
    EXPECT_EQ(1, Combinatorics::factorial(0));
    EXPECT_EQ(1, Combinatorics::factorial(1));
    try 
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(3, Combinatorics::factorial(-1));
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument &exception)
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(exception.what(), std::string("The argument cannot be negative"));
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        FAIL();
    }
    try
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(500, Combinatorics::factorial(500));
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument& exception)
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(exception.what(), std::string("The argument is too large"));
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        FAIL();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: "a tabularized approach with gamma functions" is not an optimization; it's a completely different approach.

Comment: @Teepeemm, yeah what I wanted to say that I am not talking about different algorithmic optimizations.

Comment: You're not supposed to edit the code after posting.

Comment: I think that editing the code after posting is fine.  If it makes a comment or answer seem out-of-date, a comment should be placed in the correct spot.

Comment: Initializing an `std::vector<unsigned long long> ` has some CPU overhead at program startup time, even if the `factorial` function is never called. To get rid of this, use an array instead (`const unsigned long long representableFactors[] = { ... }`).

Comment: Your new code deserves its own review. It certainly belongs elsewhere than this question, where responders ignored that solution as requested.

Comment: @JosephDoggie, if you want to propose a change to how we operate here, you should probably ask on [meta].  But don't expect a lot of support for that idea, as there's a pretty firm consensus against invalidating answers or having to edit them to remove much of the educational content.

Comment: To me, getting things correct by editing is very important.  Perhaps the code review exchange has more rigid rules.  I was told in grad school, even if you have to make a pen and ink correction to your thesis/dissertation, it's better (though more messy) than leaving a known error.  It's much easier to edit on the web than with pen and ink of course.

Comment: The largest number whose factorial can be represented in a `long long` is 29.  This means you may as well just precompute a const array of all 30 possible values and return the result in constant-time rather than compute it on the fly.  Check if the value is <0 or >29 and throw an exception, otherwise just return the value indexed from the array.

Comment: Many textbooks use recursion as a way to solve the factorial problem.  Or alternatively, use the factorial as an example to teach recursion.  However it is done, please do NOT use recursion.  Also, reading through all the answers, as often happens, exception handling for overflow, input problems (e.g. negative) etc dominates much of the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We're missing some required headers:

```
#include <climits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
```

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
```

---

We can reduce the number of division operations here:

> ```
>         if ((ULLONG_MAX / i) >= fact)
> ```

If we use `ULLONG_MAX / n` instead, we get the exception in the same cases, but this doesn't change during the loop and the compiler can hoist the calculation to perform the division just once.

If we swap the `if`/`else` around, we find we don't need `else` because throwing an exception breaks the flow of control:

> ```
>         if (fact > ULLONG_MAX / n) {
>             throw std::invalid_argument("The argument is too large");
>         }
>         fact *= i;
> ```

---

Since negative numbers don't have factorials, it may be better to accept an unsigned type as argument, so we don't need the `n < 0` test.

---

There's no need to check whether other exceptions are thrown:

> ```
> catch(...)
> {
>     FAIL();
> }
> ```

This is actually harmful, because it gives a information-free failure, whereas GTest's own handling of exceptions will report the exception that was thrown.

If the concern is that any exception will abort the test case and not run subsequent tests, then the fix is simple - create individual tests for each value.

In any case, instead of using our own `try`/`catch`, we could do better by using the framework's provided `EXPECT_THROW` macro:

```
TEST(Combinatorial_Factorial, small_ints)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(120, Combinatorics::factorial(5));
    EXPECT_EQ(1, Combinatorics::factorial(0));
    EXPECT_EQ(1, Combinatorics::factorial(1));
}

TEST(Combinatorial_Factorial, negative)
{
    EXPECT_THROW(Combinatorics::factorial(-1), std::invalid_argument);
}

TEST(Combinatorial_Factorial, too_big)
{
    EXPECT_THROW(Combinatorics::factorial(500), std::invalid_argument);
}
```

You'll see that these tests don't verify the message within the exception.  That's really a Good Thing, as the content of the message isn't (shouldn't) be part of the spec, and that level of verification is **over-testing**.

As an aside, we (theoretically at least) can't guarantee that `ULLONG_MAX` is less than 500!, since there is no upper limit imposed by the standard, only a lower limit.

---

The correct exception type to throw is really `std::overflow_error` (*result of a computation is too large for the destination type*).

---

Minor style issue: established convention is that we use lower-case names for namespace identifiers.

Minor issue:  `fact *= i` is equivalent to `fact = fact * i` and somewhat easier to take in.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <climits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

namespace combinatorics
{
    unsigned long long factorial(unsigned n)
    {
        unsigned long long fact = 1;
        for (unsigned i = 2;  i <= n;  ++i) {
            if (fact > ULLONG_MAX / n) {
                throw std::overflow_error("The result is too large");
            }
            fact *= i;
        }
        return fact;
    }
}


#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(Combinatorial_Factorial, small_ints)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(combinatorics::factorial(0), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(combinatorics::factorial(1), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(combinatorics::factorial(5), 120);
}

TEST(Combinatorial_Factorial, too_big)
{
    EXPECT_THROW(combinatorics::factorial(500), std::overflow_error);
}
```

Comment: Great insights there thanks.

Comment: **Don't** use `unsigned` just because the domain is non-negative.  See [ES.106](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es106-dont-try-to-avoid-negative-values-by-using-unsigned)

Comment: @JDługosz Disagree, yet also agree.  (I feel strongly both ways)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  What's to disagree?  It doesn't "fix" the domain problem but actually makes it worse, as the function can no longer check for invalid values.  Plus, `unsigned` is slower.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  counting up will be faster for extended types and on CPUs that don't have fully pipelined multiplication.   The test should be done outside the loop, so "sooner" is moot; it only makes it clearer how the repeated division and test is redundant.

Comment: @JDługosz "The test should be done outside the loop," is unclear.  `i > 0` is the loop test. Do you mean some other test?

Comment: @chux, downside to downcounting is that we need a division every iteration to check for overflow.

Comment: @JDługosz, with unsigned type, there is no need to check for invalid values, as _all_ values are then valid.  That's the whole point.  (And that ES.106 link seems to assume that compiler warnings aren't enabled - just enable them).

Comment: @TobySpeight Agree about downcounting.  Suggestion deleted.

Comment: @chux: because when we're downcounting, the last multiplication is by 1, not by `n`.  So we get a false positive when the result is greater than `ULLONG_MAX / n` but less than `ULLONG_MAX`.  (As JDługosz says in answer, we can precompute the largest computable input given the limit of the output type, and that would allow a nice simple downcount without introducing `i`).

Comment: If you fi the exceptions, `std::domain_error` looks more appropriate imho.

Comment: You say "We can reduce the number of division operations here:" but you don't extract `ULLONG_MAX / n` to a variable, so you actually don't reduce the number of division operations... Correct?

Comment: Also, why not declare `unsigned i = 2` rather than `unsigned i = 1` to avoid useless multiplications?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, any decent compiler will hoist `ULLONG_MAX / n` out of the loop; you can store it in a variable if you prefer.  Yes, it would make sense to start the loop at `i = 2`; I'll edit.

Comment: I'm wondering how costly it would be to essentially reverse the factorial computation in order to find the largest `n` possible, then just use that instead of checking `fact` at every loop iteration. May be overkill, though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think JDługosz's suggestion to find it as a compile-time constant using `constexpr` calculation is better.  Or use `std::tgamma()` to get a `double` approximation to the factorial, and test that against `ULLONG_MAX`.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Yes, I hadn't seen JDługosz's answer, and we're essentially saying the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

You should write it as a template rather than hard-coding it to produce `unsigned long long`.  You might want to call it with 128-bit integers (a gnu extension), or a Bignum class of some kind such as Boost.Multiprecision.

Rather than using C's limits macros (`ULLONG_MAX`), use the C++ [`numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) library feature.  This is template-friendly, and that helps even if you are not writing template code:  you don't have to remember *different* names for the limit based on the type, and finding and fixing these when you change the type of something.

---

For the exception, you can include the function name in the error message without complicating the code.  You'll be glad of this if the error is ever hit in real code rather than in trivial test code where you're only calling one function!

As Toby pointed out, you can move the test outside of the loop.  (Division is *very expensive* and will take far longer than the actual factorial computation, as written!).  But I'll add to that:  Find the maximum legal input value as a `constexpr` local variable.  This will be computed at compile time.  But if it's a template, the specified type (some big-int library) might not support `constexpr` arithmetic if it's not fairly recent, so use `static const` instead, so it will be computed once and reused on subsequent calls to the function.

---

Another tip:  concerning `std::string("The argument cannot be negative")`, assuming you really need to explicitly make it a `std::string` rather than just passing the lexical string literal, you can use the [string literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) with identical meaning:  `"The argument cannot be negative"s`.
**Update:** because the reason is to have `==` work, it's far more efficient to use a `std::string_view`.  That not only prevents copying the characters, but the comparison is much faster than `strcmp`.
Write:  `"The argument cannot be negative"sv`.
(read the link above to learn how to opt-in to enable these literals)

Comment: Good idea to compile-time compute the max value.  I was trying to think how we could compute inverse-factorial of `ULLONG_MAX`, but of course we don't need to do that - we can loop until we're about to overflow and record that value, all in `constexpr` with favourable types.

Comment: The reason to construct a `std::string` is because `ASSERT_EQ` will use `==` to test the assertion.  We don't want to be comparing two `const char*` (as that's pointer equality), so converting one to string object gives us the value equality we want.  @suryasis, you'll need `using namespace std::literals;` for that - it's a namespace designed to be used that way, unlike `namespace std`.

Comment: maximum value for an unsigned type is easier to just calculate as needed: `T(-1)`.

Comment: @TobySpeight to get `==` to work naturally, it's more efficient to use a `string_view`.  This also has a literal form using the `""sv` suffix.  (I have a Code Project article in draft promoting this, in fact.)

Comment: @Deduplicator If `T` is not a primitive type but something like Boost.Multiprecision, or a "safe integer" wrapper (see the 2021 _CPPNow!_ conference videos) that trick will not work.

Comment: Imho, that's moving the goal-posts, as `std::numeric_limits` doesn't really work with either.