# Combination function for a math library in C++

Tags: c++, beginner

Taking forward the combinatorial library [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/265688/factorial-function-for-a-math-library-in-c), I have tried to implement the nCr function. Please mention if this is prone to failing somewhere

1. Any other test code that needs to be added.
2. Any more efficient way to code this.

N.B: I am aware that overflow handling has to be taken into consideration, that is a work in progress.

**Code**

```
// MathLibrary.cpp: Defines the functions for the static library.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


// TODO: This is an example of a library function
namespace Combinatorics
{
    const std::vector<unsigned long long> representableFactors = {1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800,39916800,
        479001600,6227020800,87178291200,1307674368000,20922789888000,355687428096000,6402373705728000,121645100408832000,2432902008176640000};

    unsigned long long factorial(unsigned int n) 
    {
        if (n >= representableFactors.size())
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Combinatorics:factorial - The argument is too large");
        }
        return representableFactors[n];
    }
    //CODE to be reviewed.
    inline unsigned long long gcd(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b)
    {
        if (a % b == 0)
            return b;
        return gcd(b, (a % b));
    }

    unsigned long long combinations(int n, int r)
    {
        if (n - r < r)
            r = n - r;
        unsigned long long int denominatorProduct = 1, numeratorProduct = 1;
        for (int denomCount = r, numCount = n ; denomCount >= 1; denomCount--, numCount--)
        {
            denominatorProduct = denominatorProduct * denomCount;
            numeratorProduct = numeratorProduct * numCount;
            unsigned gcdCommonFactor = gcd(denominatorProduct, numeratorProduct);
            denominatorProduct /= gcdCommonFactor;
            numeratorProduct /= gcdCommonFactor;
        }
        return (numeratorProduct / denominatorProduct);
    }

}
```

**Test code**

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "../MathLibrary/MathLibrary.cpp"

TEST(Combinatorial_Factorial, small_ints)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(Combinatorics::factorial(0), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(Combinatorics::factorial(1), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(Combinatorics::factorial(5), 120);
    EXPECT_EQ(Combinatorics::factorial(20), 2432902008176640000);
}

TEST(Combinatorial_Factorial, too_big)
{
    EXPECT_THROW(Combinatorics::factorial(500), std::invalid_argument);
}

TEST(Combinatorial_Combinations, small_ints)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(Combinatorics::combinations(5,5), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(Combinatorics::combinations(5, 0), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(Combinatorics::combinations(5, 1), 5);
    EXPECT_EQ(Combinatorics::combinations(20,10),184756);
    EXPECT_EQ(Combinatorics::combinations(40, 35),658008);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I’ll ignore the factorial code, since that was already reviewed in your previous question.

In `combinations()`, what would happen if `r>n`? What if either input is negative? Neither case appears in your test set, and is not tested for in the function either. Unsigned arithmetic with a negative signed integer leads to overflow and headaches…

In

```cpp
if (n - r < r)
    r = n - r;
```

you should prefer to use braces. I think they increase readability. There is also an famous story about a bug introduced because of the missing braces: it is easy to add a line of code and think it is inside the conditional, when it’s not. I don’t know how true this is, but GCC added a warning when the indentation is misleading, presumably to address that situation in the legend.

Here:

```cpp
unsigned long long int denominatorProduct = 1, numeratorProduct = 1;
```

I would prefer two lines, one declaration per line. Again to improve readability.

You could think of declaring some integer types to use across your library, avoiding the repeated use of `unsigned long long int` and the like. Not just to make the type name shorter, but also to add some flexibility and consistency.

Instead of

```cpp
denominatorProduct = denominatorProduct * denomCount;
```

write:

```cpp
denominatorProduct *= denomCount;
```

This is easier to read. You do use this notation for the division later on. Try to be consistent with your syntax!

Comment: Not a legend, many people have added a line to code that didn't have braces and expected to be part of the condition, although that was 30 years ago. The company I worked for at the time created a coding standard that said you must use braces in ever condition or loop.

Answer (score 2):

## Unit tests

It's great that you have included unit tests for these functions.  That makes reviewing and proposing modifications much easier than otherwise.  Thank you!

---

## Naming

It's normal to write header files for inclusion with a name ending in `.h`.  **`MathLibrary.cpp`** is likely to be mistaken for the top level of a translation unit (aka an *implementation* file).

On further inspection, it appears that it actually is an implementation file, but used wrongly - included into the program's main translation unit, rather than being compiled separately, then linked to form the final executable.

We need to extract its definitions into a header file than can be used by both, and an implementation file that can be compiled separately and linked together.

---

## Headers

I needed to include `<stdexcept>` for the code to compile, and `<gtest.h>` for the test program.  I also removed the unused/unavailable headers `<iostream>`, `"pch.h"` and `"framework.h"`.

---

## Warnings

GCC complains about

> ```
>        unsigned gcdCommonFactor = gcd(denominatorProduct, numeratorProduct);
> ```

`gcdCommonFactor` needs to be `unsigned long long` here - or simply `auto`, which will deduced to the correct type.

---

## Factorial function

This definition makes unwarranted assumptions about `sizeof (unsigned long long)`:

> ```
> const std::vector<unsigned long long> representableFactors = {1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800,39916800,
>     479001600,6227020800,87178291200,1307674368000,20922789888000,355687428096000,6402373705728000,121645100408832000,2432902008176640000};
> ```

Luckily, it should give you compilation errors if the type is too small for the integer literals, though it leaves your code under-performing if the type is larger than you expect.

Since it's used only in the `factorial()` function, perhaps it would be better as a static local within that function.  And since it has constant size, use `std::array`:

```
static constexpr std::array representableFactors = { 1ull, 1ull, 2ull, ... };
```

Having done that, it then seems easier to turn `factorial()` into a `switch`:

```
unsigned long long factorial(unsigned int n) 
{
    switch (n) {
    case 0: return 1;
    case 1: return 1;
    case 2: return 2;
    case 3: return 6;
    case 4: return 24;
    case 5: return 120;
    case 6: return 720;
    case 7: return 5040;
    case 8: return 40320;
    case 9: return 362880;
    case 10: return 3628800;
    case 11: return 39916800;
    case 12: return 479001600;
    case 13: return 6227020800;
    case 14: return 87178291200;
    case 15: return 1307674368000;
    case 16: return 20922789888000;
    case 17: return 355687428096000;
    case 18: return 6402373705728000;
    case 19: return 121645100408832000;
    case 20: return 2432902008176640000;
    }
    throw std::overflow_error("Combinatorics::factorial - result too large");
}
```

Note also the choice of a more appropriate exception type.

However, this still fails to adapt to the size of the targets `unsigned long long` type.  We can make a version that adapts properly, creating (at compile-time) a table of factorials that's as large as the platform can compute:

```
template<typename ResultType = std::uintmax_t>
ResultType factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    constexpr auto results_table
        = []{
            constexpr unsigned int max_factorial_input
                = []{
                    auto max_result = std::numeric_limits<ResultType>::max();
                    ResultType f = 1;
                    auto i = 1u;
                    while (max_result / i >= (f *= i)) {
                        ++i;
                    }
                    return i;
                }();
            std::array<ResultType, max_factorial_input + 1> table;
            table[0] = 1;
            for (auto i = 1u;  i < table.size();  ++i) {
                table[i] = table[i-1] * i;
            }
            return table;
        }();

    if (n >= results_table.size()) {
        throw std::overflow_error("Combinatorics::factorial - result too large");
    }
    return results_table[n];
}
```

---

## GCD function

This function can be declared `constexpr`.  Consider refactoring to the iterative form.

A generic (template) version is probably useful, so we can return a type that agrees with the arguments:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::common_type_t<T, U> gcd(T t, U u);
```

Add some checking so that we never attempt to divide by zero.

Preferably, remove the entire function, since `std::gcd()` (in header `<numeric>`) has all the above features.

---

## Combinations function

I don't see why we're accepting (signed) integer arguments here - unsigned makes more sense.

It's good that we replace `r` with `n-r` when that makes for less work.

Consider tests of invalid argument combinations (include these in the unit tests!).   We know we can't choose more than `n` items, so if `r > n` we should return 0 (or throw an exception?).

We can perform some known divisions because we know that the product of any *n* consecutive integers must be a multiple of *n*! (since those integers must contain at least one multiple of each integer up to *n*).  That means we don't need to keep a running denominator - if we count upwards, it will always be 1.

It's also a good idea to test for overflow during the computation - an exception is better than an incorrect value.

```
template<typename ResultType = std::uintmax_t>
ResultType combinations(unsigned int n, unsigned int r)
{
    constexpr auto max_result = std::numeric_limits<ResultType>::max();

    if (n < r) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (n - r < r) {
        r = n - r;
    }

    ResultType result = 1;
    for (auto ri = 1u;   ri <= r;  ++ri) {
        if (result > max_result / n) {
            throw std::overflow_error("Combinatorics::combination - result too large");
        }
        result *= n--;
        result /= ri;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Again, I've parameterised the result type here, as it might be useful to get an approximate floating-point value when the exact result is too big for the available integer types.  Or we might want to use an arbitrary-precision library such as GMP.

Comment: That file _is_ an implementation file.  The first thing defined (`representableFactors`) is not inlined.  The following function (`factorial`) is not inlined either, nor is `combinations`.  This cannot be a header, since multiple inclusions will give linker errors.  I notice the internal helper _is_ declared `inline` which indicates a misunderstanding of what that will do for you (it should be `static`).

Comment: Ah, so I needed to recommend extracting a header so that both implementation files can reference the same definitions.

Comment: With regard to the `switch`, I’d probably go with a lookup table?

Comment: @Davislor - that's exactly what I did immediately after (the one that contains a table of the appropriate length).  A compiler could make the `switch` into a table by itself, of course, and possibly with better locality than one you make by hand.  Swings and roundabouts...

Comment: @TobySpeight note `#include "../MathLibrary/MathLibrary.cpp"` in the test file.  He's not doing multi-source files right.  It's not compiled separately, and it will only work in a case like this where there is one translation unit.

Comment: Yes, that's what made me believe it was intended to be a header file.